# TreeMap prints package.bean@numbers and not the values requested

Tags: java

I have a problem printing the values of a TreeMap.

I have the following bean:

```
 package dizionari;

 import dizionari.Main.Lingua;

 public class Parola implements java.io.Serializable {

     private String stringa;
     private Lingua lingua;

     public Parola() {}

     public void setStringa(String stringa) {
         this.stringa = stringa;
     }

     public String getStringa() {
         return this.stringa;
     }

     public void setLingua(Lingua lingua) {
         this.lingua = lingua;
     }

     public Lingua getLingua() {
         return this.lingua;
     }  
 }
```

And here is my main class. When I type "Casa", the output is strange: it appears to be `"package.bean@numbers+chars"`. What does this mean?

```
"`Traduzioni di Casa: [dizionari.Parola@15db9742, dizionari.Parola@15db9742]`"
```

Code

```
     public class Main {

     enum Lingua {ITALIANO, INGLESE, FRANCESE};  

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         TreeMap<String, List<Parola>> dizionarioMultilingua;
         dizionarioMultilingua = new TreeMap<String, List<Parola>>();

         List<Parola> listUno = new ArrayList<>();

         Parola casa = new Parola();

         casa.setStringa("Maison");
         casa.setLingua(Lingua.FRANCESE);

         listUno.add(casa);

         casa.setStringa("House");
         casa.setLingua(Lingua.INGLESE);

         listUno.add(casa);
         dizionarioMultilingua.put("Casa", listUno);

         String stringa = null;

         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

         System.out.println("La lista dei termini disponibili è ");

         for (String key : dizionarioMultilingua.keySet()) {
             System.out.println("-"+key);
         }

         System.out.println("Scrivi qualcosa qui e poi premi invio...");

         try {
             stringa = in.readLine();

             if (stringa != null) {
                 if (stringa.equals("fine")) {
                     System.out.println("Programma terminato");
                 }  else if (stringa.equals("Casa")) {
                     System.out.println("Traduzioni di "+stringa+": "+dizionarioMultilingua.get("Casa"));
                 }
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You need to override `toString()` in your `Parola` class.

Comment: Search Google for [java print map content](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=java%20print%20map%20content&oq=java%20print%20map%20co&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.4259j0j7)